# eclipse didn't do apk with proguard.cfg

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, proguard

If i would like create apk with proguard, eclipe, he tell me this and didn't do apk

```
  ava.io.IOException: Can't read [proguard.ClassPathEntry@6d632c2d] (No such file or directory)
```

I have test the solution sujest in this links:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18359
and this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2...n-external-jar

I think i have this message because proguard don't compil because they have problem's with jar library. How resolve this problem's?

this are the content of proprieties

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

this are the content of proguard file

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {    
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search, the problem's was because i used iText library. The OpenSource library didn't works with proguard. for a library that works with proguard must take a paid version.